# Intergrate google adwords tracking with salesforce

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, salesforce

im trying to integrate google adwords tracking with salesforce based on this
https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/integrate-salesforce-and-google-analytics

i have created hidden fields in salesforce and add the code to the form and the js script to capture the values but i having problem i dont get any data coming in

> ```
> test.php?utm_source=google&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=test&utm_term=test
>
> <input type="hidden" name="medium" id="medium" value="" />
> <input type="hidden" name="source" id="source" value="" />
> <input type="hidden" name="campaign" id="campaign" value="" />
> <input type="hidden" name="term" id="term" value="" />
> ```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var z = _uGC(document.cookie, '__utmz=', ';');
var source = _uGC(z, 'utmcsr=', '|');
var medium = _uGC(z, 'utmcmd=', '|');
var term = _uGC(z, 'utmctr=', '|');
var content = _uGC(z, 'utmcct=', '|');
var campaign = _uGC(z, 'utmccn=', '|');
var gclid = _uGC(z, 'utmgclid=', '|');
if (gclid !="-") {
 source = 'google';
 medium = 'cpc';
}

var csegment = _uGC(document.cookie, '__utmv=', ';');
if (csegment != '-') {
 var csegmentex = /[1-9]*?\.(.*)/;
 csegment = csegment.match(csegmentex);
 csegment = csegment[1];

} else {
 csegment = '';
}

function _uGC(l,n,s)
{
if (!l || l=="" || !n || n=="" || !s || s=="") return "-";
var i,i2,i3,c="-";
i=l.indexOf(n);
i3=n.indexOf("=")+1;
if (i > -1) {
i2=l.indexOf(s,i); if (i2 < 0){ i2=l.length; }
c=l.substring((i+i3),i2);
}
return c;
}
document.getElementById("medium").value =medium; /* Campaign_Medium */
document.getElementById("source").value =source; /* Campaign_Source */
document.getElementById("campaign").value =campaign; /* Campaign_CampaignName */
document.getElementById("term").value =term; /* Campaign_Term */
</script>
```

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious, do you actually work with "classic" GA ? Because the current version does not have an utmz-cookie, so with Universal Analytics this approach would fail.

Comment: i looked  the source looks like this one is being used and it does have utmz http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js is there a better to check if it classic or universal?

Comment: No it doesn't. "ga.js" used cookies to store campaign info, analytics.js (Universal Analytics) does not (it just has a _ga cookie that holds the session id).  I have an idea how to import the information into SF, but that would require a bit of serverside programming, I'm not sure how comfortable you are with that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if I understand correctly you are trying to do a Web-to-Lead process and you want to capture the campaign information.

As I see it your current approach has two major flaws: The current version of Google Analytics (Universal Analytics, which uses the analytics.js tracking library) does not evaluate campaign information on the client side and does not store in in the cookie (UA uses a single cookie that only hold a client id).

But even if it did it would probably not help you with your Adwords data. Chances are pretty good that you have autotagging enabled, and in that you would not have campaign information for Adwords even with the old Google Analytics code. Adwords uses a Google Click id, or gclid, that is resolved into readable campaign parameters only after GA has retrieved to information from a linked Adwords account; on the client side you can only read the gclid parameter which does not help you.

So I suggest a different approach that should work well as long as you do not need the data in realtime, and as long as you a prepared to do some serverside programming instead of Javascript (which simply cannot do what you want). It goes basically like this:

Instead of sending campaign data along with your Web-To-Lead form you send just a unique id for the lead, and store in a custom field in Salesforce. You send the same id to Google Analytics as custom dimension that you have created before in a hit level scope by attaching a click event to the submit button (or submit event to the form), send a Google Analytics event and include the id as custom dimension.

Google Analytics needs a bit of processing time, so you wait until the next day. By then GA will have resolved the Adwords click ids into readable source/medium/campaign parameters (plus term and content if you need that, and it will have imported Adwords-related metrics).

You then query the Google Analytics Reporting API to retrieve the submit events from GA with your custom id and the campaign information. Then you send the campaign data via the Salesforce API to SF and store it in custom fields in your lead entities. Run the script once periodically and it will update all your leads with the data from GA.

The biggest drawback is possibly that API access is not available for all Salesforce editions. According to this knowledgebase article API access is enabled in Enterprise/Unlimited/Performance and Developer editions and can be enabled for a fee in the professional edition.

It has turned out to be impossible for me to cram instructions for the whole process into an stackoverflow post, so I wrote a tutorial that covers all steps. This requires some serverside programming - the tutorial uses python, and it should include enough information to get the program running even if you do not know Python. It's broken up into several parts, so you can skip the bits you are already familiar with.

- [Part 1 -  Restating the Problem](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-1/)
- [Part 2 - The Programming Environment used in the  tutorial](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-2/)
- [Part 3 - APIs and Authentication](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-3/)
- [Part 4 - Setting up Salesforce and Google Analytics](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-4/)
- [Part 5 - Libraries and example code](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/import-ga-information-to-salesforce-part-5/)

It might be that the links will be removed for being to self-promotional (they lead to my blog), but even so this post should give you an idea how to approach the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you are using the correct codes and the correct sequence to do that, check [my post here](https://www.wisamabdulaziz.com/how-to-pass-google-analytics-traffic-source-dimensions-salesforce.htm) and use the same codes and instructions I am using to track Source, Medium, Campaign and Term, I fully tested it and it is working fine.

Your approach is correct, but I am not sure if you are trying to read the cookies before they are even created, if this is your landing page test.php?utm_source=google&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=test&utm_term=test   and it is the same page where you are trying to fill the hidden fields make sure the Javascript code/function that generates the cookies (function _uGC) get executed before the code that tries to fill in the fields

Comment: It appears the main part of this answer is: "Go find the real answer on my blog". That's really not appropriate for Stack Overflow. While you can link to off-site resources (even your own, if you state they are your own, as you do), such links should only be for supplementary information. Users shouldn't be required to click through to some other site to get the actual answer. Please [add enough information so that to make this an actual answer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259).